# SQLite database gets locked by SELECT clause

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a python script which creates a database and then enters an infinite loop which runs once per second querying the database with some selects.

At the same time I connect to the database with a sqlite cli and try to make an update but I get a database is locked error.

Here the (anonymized) code of the script:

```
import sqlite3
import time

con = sqlite3.connect(r'path\to\database.sqlite')

con.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS blah;')
con.execute('CREATE TABLE blah;')
con.execute('INSERT INTO blah;')

con.commit()

while True:
    result = con.execute('SELECT blah')
    print(result.fetchone()[0])
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You may want to close the cursor after `fetchone`, `result.close()`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I'm afraid it didn't work

Comment: Then CL.'s answer below probably helps, didn't know about the transaction management built in.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `sqlite3` module tries to be clever and [manages transactions for you](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions).

To ensure that you can access the database from other threads/processes, disable that (set `isolation_level` to `None`), and use explicit transactions, when needed.
Alternatively, call `con.commit()` whenever you are finished.

Comment: I tried the isolation_level "trick" before asking here and it didn't work, I'm sorry I didn't mention it. Also as you can see in the code I commit after creating the database, in the loop I only use SELECT clauses which don't need a commit.